# Using YouTube Data API v3 to automate scheduling live streams, I am getting an Error Code: 400

Tags: java, json, automation, youtube

I am writing a Java program to automate the scheduling of our weekly live streams for our YouTube channel. I am using the YouTube Data API v3. I am trying to send the simple JSON file with minimal information just to get the stream up and running as a test.

When I try to run my program, I get this Error Code: 400 back.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "'status'",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "'status'",
        "domain": "youtube.part",
        "reason": "unexpectedPart",
        "location": "part",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what is included in the JSON file that I am using.

```
{
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": "****",
    "title": "Thursday Bible Study & Prayer Meeting (July 13, 2023)",
    "description": "Test description"
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "madeForKids": false
  }
}
```